# How to shut down external application gracefully?

Tags: windows

I have a program that shuts down another application when certain conditions are met. Now most of the time everything works out fine, but sometimes the app is writing to a file and leaves it in a half finished state and has no way of recovering it on restart. I thought that one could send soft close signals and escalate after certain timeouts to more aggressive close signals, going trough a list like this:

```
  1. WM_CLOSE

  2. WM_QUIT

  3. WM_DESTROY

  4. TerminateProcess().
```

Now I know that the program has no code to handle any signal it receives. Is there a possibility that certain FileHandler under Windows react gracefully on such soft signals or is there no use to sending those, if the app does not handle them explicitly?
This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178893/how-to-terminate-an-application-cleanly-in-win32) says:

> NOTE: A console application's response to WM_CLOSE depends on whether or not it has installed a control handler.

Does this mean if no control handler is installed sending 1-4 is just as good as sending 4 directly?

Comment: *the program has no code to handle any signal it receives.* - in this case impossible shut down gracefully. `WM_DESTROY` post/send at all absolute senseless and wrong.

Comment: This is what I thought, but wanted to make sure. Do you maybe have a source?

Comment: source of what ?

Comment: This information. While it is unlikely certain objects from a language could react to signals, even if the program does not. But I guess this would be rare, I wonder if a language exists with such features.

Comment: If a console app doesn't have a control handler to get the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` notice, the default control handler still executes on the injected control thread. The default handler calls `ExitProcess`, which calls the entry point of all DLLs with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. Maybe some cleanup can occur there. However, all of the other threads in the process are immediately terminated, so that's of a little help if a thread is in the middle of writing to a file.